# Cursor url property does not seem to work on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

`<body style="CURSOR: url('arrr.ani')"> hello </body>`

Why the above CSS property does not work on Google Chrome and works on IE, if only the cursor is over the word `hello` in IE. I want to use my own cursor for my webpage, I wanted to use a black cursor on my website. Where am I going wrong or is it possible to change the color of cursor to black?

### Update

But works here check out this website http://www.anicursor.com/webcursor.html. The owner of the website used his own cursor, I used the same property but it does not seem to work with me.

Comment: Put the absolute path to your .ani file.. chances are it can't find it. Do you have firebug? Check errors, does it say that it could not load it?

Comment: @KyleR sorry i dont have firebug what is it though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I change a cursor in standards mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104472/css-why-cant-i-change-a-cursor-in-standards-mode)

Comment: but to the gods grace it does not work :( on my pc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As BoltClock said, try the following:

```
<body style="cursor: url('arrr.ani'), default">
```

Adding default makes firefox and chrome validate the `cursor` rule.